# Issue managing state of an operator for messages with the same timestamp using Flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I seem to be encountering an issue while managing state during parallel processing of messages with the same key and the same timestamp.

For (simplified) example let's suppose a simple `DoFn<Key, Long>` with a `ValueState<Long>`.

```
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(
      final ProcessContext c,
      @StateId(STATE_ID)
          final ValueState<Long> someState) {
      final long val = c.element().value();
      final long currentSum = Optional.ofNullable(someState.read()).orElse(0L);
      final long newSum = currentSum + val;
      someState.write(newSum);
}
```

This state is outputted intermittently on some timer.

My question is in the case where there are 2 elements `A` and `B` which both have the same `Key` and timestamp. The value in state is `5`, the value of `A` is 3, and the value of `B` is 4. One would expect the value in `someState` after processing both elements to be 12. My question is this guaranteed? That is, will some ordering be applied elements to `A` and `B` - or does there possibly exist a race condition whereby the value in state can intermittently either be 8 or 9 depending on whether `A` or `B` are processed first. (Note: This is a simplified version of what I am dealing with but I believe this is undeterministic behavior is happening our pipleine). If this assumption is correct what approaches could I take in order to resolve this issue?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no race condition caused by identical timestamps. You'll get called twice, once for each element.

Comment: In what order is the operator called for each element? Is it nondeterministic?

Comment: There's no implicit ordering of records. You can get ordered records from a source (assuming the source is emitting records in a defined order), but once you run through a `keyBy()` the resulting stream of values with the same key has no guaranteed order.